# Difference between decision tree and logistic regression for multi-class classification

Tags: regression, cart

What's the difference (Advantages and Disadvantages) between decision tree and logistic regression for multi-class classification? I referenced some answers of decision tree (`not sure all right and complete`):

> Advantages: easy for understanding and interpretation; more suitable to deal with samples with missing feature values.

> Disadvantages: easy for Overfitting; easy to ignore the correlation of features in the data set.

I don't much understand:

1. Overfitting: logistic regression is also easy for overfitting, therefore we will use regularization. For tree, the techniques like pruning, bagging e.t.c are also used to avoid overfitting. How could we say that tree is easy for overfitting compared with regression?
2. Correlation:  How to understand that the tree ignores the correlation between features? In regression, we also want to reduce the collinearity between features, does the linear model capture the correlation between features?
3. Are there any other important differences missed?

Comment: The discontinuities in the expected value function are obviously wrong with trees. Linearity is also wrong, but not quite so blatantly wrong.

Comment: @BigBendRegion pls see the update. Let me change into logistic regression to focus on the multi-class classification.

Comment: Same answer, nearly. The discontinuities of the tree model are obviously wrong as regards the true probability function. Linearity of the logit probability function is also wrong, but not as blatantly wrong. Nature favors continuity over discontinuity.

Comment: @BigBendRegion but we only consider the classification problem which means discrete on lable (y) and continuous on variable (x). Tree and logistic regression are widely used models for such problem. Where is wrong?

Comment: There is a true probability function. Classifications are based on this function. This true function belongs to the data generating process, not the data. Nature does not choose to make this function linear, logit linear, or piecewise flat. In other words, Nature does not care whether we humans find such functions pleasing or convenient. Nature will instead choose functions that actually govern the process. These comments apply to statistical models, in general.

Comment: @BigBendRegion maybe what's your think is more deep than what I asked. But currently let's just focus on the practice. Do you agree that `Tree and logistic regression are widely used models for Classifications problem.` If agree, could you answer my three questions?